# How to know percentage or increase/decrease using \scalebox command

Tags: scalebox, percentage

In my document, one of the image is coded as `\scalebox{0.25}{\includegraphics{map.eps}}`, please confirm what is the percentage they enlarged or reduced

Comment: The `0.25` in the first argument is the scale factor. So the image will be reduced to 0.25 * 100% = 25% of its natural size. But is this really the question? If not the question is unclear at least to me. BTW: Using `graphicx` you could simply use `\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{map}` for the same. See the [`grfguide`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) for more information about `\scalebox` and `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will use the scale option as you suggested

Comment: @Schweinebacke one more image is tagged as "\scalebox{1}{\includegraphics{letters.eps}}", sorry to ask again what is the percentage of enlargement/decrease of the image

Comment: Again, `1` is the scale factor here, so the image will be reduced to 1*100%=100%, i.e. it will just be printed in its full size. Here, you can just leave out the `\scalebox` part completely.

Comment: Please read the manual I've linked above!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `\scalebox{<factor>}{<material>}` will make a box out of the `<material>`. Then it will multiply each dimension of this box by the `<factor>`.

So, if the `<material>` turns out to be 10cm wide and 6cm high, with

```
\scalebox{0.25}{<material>}
```

TeX will scale the box so that it will be 10cm · 0.25 = 2.5cm wide and 6cm · 0.25 = 1.5cm high.

If the argument is `1`, then no scaling will take place (more precisely, the dimensions will be multiplied by 1).

What should `<material>` be? Anything that LaTeX can treat as a single object: a letter, a word, a tabular environment, a `minipage` or, as in your case, `\includegraphics`.

However, `graphicx` allows for a better interface:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{map}
```

is the same as

```
\scalebox{0.25}{\includegraphics{map}}
```

Comment: We always knew @egreg was the master of all things related to `%`